# Why can't you call a method on a null pointer in Java?

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception, go, this

In Go, it is OK to call a method on a null pointer so long as that pointer is never dereferenced:

```go
type empty struct{}
func (e *empty) Allocated() bool { return e != nil }
```

(For runnable code, click [here](http://play.golang.org/p/y7QHshrU30))

In Java, however, calling a method on a null pointer, even if the method never dereferences any member variables, still causes a null pointer exception:

```java
class Test {
    public boolean Allocated() { return this != null; }
}
```

Does anybody know why this behavior exists? Is there some advantage that it gives? Thoughts?

Comment: You can, if it's a static method.

Comment: You mean you like this?
`class Test { public static boolean Good() { return true; } }`
`Test t = null;`
`t.Good();`

Comment: @joshlf13: yup. It's treated identically to `Test.Good()` by the compiler

Comment: @newacct: Actually, it looks like they're not statically resolved. Because of subclassing, the compiler can't know at compile-time what type the variable will hold at runtime. See this example: http://pastebin.com/JKrHjcWS

Comment: @joshlf13: Umm.. how does your code show that it is not statically resolved?

Comment: If you run it, you'll see that while the variable has the same compile-time type in both instances, different functions are called at run-time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because all Java methods are virtual.

When you write `someInstance.Allocated()`, the runtime needs to check whether `someInstance` is actually of a derived type that overrides the method.

In theory, this restriction could have been relaxed for `final` or `private` methods.
I assume that the language designers chose not to for consistency.  (and so that removing `final` wouldn't be a breaking change)

Comment: They're methods,  not functions, and they aren't all virtual. Statics, privates, and finals are non-virtual.

Comment: @EJP: Statics don't have an instance parameter, and I already mentioned final.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by *SLaks* is good from a Java perspective. I don't have a clue about Java but I know Go and here's my answer:

First of all `nil` is not the same as a `NULL` pointer, there are [some fundamental differences](http://blog.denevell.org/golang-null-nil.html).

Then, methods in Go are not part of a type's instance but the type itself i.e. Go does not store the vtable inside objects, like Java does:

```
var e *empty
fmt.Println(e.Allocated())
```

is the same as… (syntactic sugar for…):

```
var e *empty
fmt.Println((*empty).Allocated(e)) // This is valid code
```

Note how `Allocated` is invoked as a member of `*empty`, much like a static method in traditional *"OOP"* languages.

In fact, `(*empty).Allocated` is just a function name with a weird notation that includes a dot, an asterisk and parens.

Because the receiver is just another argument, the fact that it is `nil` is unimportant to the method dispatch mechanism.

> In Go, it is OK to call a method on a null pointer so long as that pointer is never dereferenced

If by OK you mean legal, then it's even OK to call a method on a `nil` value and dereferencing it. The compiler won't complain - you'll just get a runtime panic.

Comment: I meant OK as in won't panic.

Comment: But that's really cool; That de-sugared version implies some really cool language hacks you could do. For example, check out the functions in encoding/binary's "binary.go" file:
http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/binary/binary.go

Comment: Right, and one of the reasons that that syntactic sugar is possible is that types in Go are not polymorphic, and their methods are not virtual.

Comment: @joshlf13: can you be more specific about these "language hacks"?

Comment: Well, for example, in the file I linked to in my first comment (http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/binary/binary.go), they use the language's built-in type resolution to perform a switch. They have two different encodings, and as it looks to the user, you do:

`Uint16(BigEndian, b)`, but instead of using the /value/ of BigEndian to switch on, they use the /type/ of BigEndian to figure out which function to call. It's really cool.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's a philosophical issue; methods (except for static methods) *apply* to an object, by their very nature, and calling a method like that on a non-object like "null" just doesn't make sense in this paradigm.  If you want to define a method that can apply to an object or to "null", it's easy enough to define a static method that does that, and in my opinion that would make the code that calls the method less confusing to readers.

Comment: Actually, I think that there's a much more practical consideration, as @SLaks pointed out.

Comment: @joshlf3: The practical consideration is there.  However, I do think that some languages do have things like readability as part of their design philosophies, and thus don't let you do things that don't make sense even if it _could_ be implemented.  Ada is in that category (and I'm very familiar with the discussions that go into the design of that language), and I think Java is in the same category; as opposed to C, Perl, and I think Javascript and PHP, where the philosophy is pretty much to let programmers write any way they want.  Just my opinion.